# Как запустить .bat файл в приложение Delphi без прав администратора?

Tags: windows, delphi-7, cmd, bat, права

.bat файл корректно работает при запуске из приложения Delphi с правами администратора, но без прав он просто не находит файл. Приложение установлено в папку Program Files. В других не системных папках без прав выполняется корректно. Как обойти это ограничение?

```
procedure RunBatchFile;
var
  List: TStringList;
  ShExecInfo: SHELLEXECUTEINFO;
begin
  if not FileExists(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'config.ini') then
    try
      try
        if (FileExists(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'get_ip.bat')) or
          (FileExists(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'ip.txt')) then
        begin
          DeleteFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'get_ip.bat');
          DeleteFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'ip.txt');
        end;

        List := TStringList.Create;
        List.Add('@echo off');
        List.Add('cls');
        List.Add('for /f "usebackq tokens=4" %%A in (`route print ^| findstr "\<0.0.0.0"`) do echo %%A > ip.txt');
        List.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'get_ip.bat');

        ZeroMemory(@ShExecInfo, SizeOf(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));

        with ShExecInfo do
        begin
          cbSize := SizeOf(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
          fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
          lpFile := PChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'get_ip.bat');
          nShow := SW_HIDE;
        end;

        ShellExecuteEx(@ShExecInfo);
        WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);

        List.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'ip.txt');

        edtIP.Text := Trim(List.Text);
        edtPort.Text := '5432';
        edtUser.Text := 'postgres';
        edtPassword.Text := 'passwd';
        Exit;
      except
        on E: Exception do
          ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
      end;
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Где проверка на ошибки? Что возвращает `GetLastError`?

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил проверку. Пишет "Отказано в доступе"

Comment: Откуда у Вас возникает исключение? Его не должно быть. ShellExecute - это функция и она возвращает результат

Comment: Привел полный код, исключение возникает при попытке сохранения batch файла в Program Files\MyApp. Так же не происходит удаление, если файл уже есть. `ShellExecuteEx` запускает `get_ip.bat`, но сам код в файле не сохраняет данные в папку Program Files\MyApp. При запуске от администратора код выполняется корректно, без прав - "Отказано в доступе"

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? У Вас ошибка при удалении, а вопрос задается "как запустить?"

Comment: Не издеваюсь (вы просили показать где возникает исключение). Даже если опустить тот факт что он не может удалить без прав администратора, все равно batch файл не сохраняет данные в папку, пока приложение от имени администратора не запуститься. Вопрос остался актуальным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работайте с файлом в каталоге `Temp`

```
function GetTempPath: string;
var
  LLen: Cardinal;
begin
  LLen := Win32Check(Windows.GetTempPath(0, nil));
  SetLength(Result, LLen - 1);
  Win32Check(Windows.GetTempPath(LLen, @Result[1]));
end;

procedure RunBatchFile;
var
  List: TStringList;
  ShExecInfo: SHELLEXECUTEINFO;
  Name: string;
begin
  if FileExists(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'config.ini') then
    Exit;
  try
    List := TStringList.Create;
    try
      List.Add('@echo off');
      List.Add('cls');
      List.Add('for /f "usebackq tokens=4" %%A in (`route print ^| findstr "\<0.0.0.0"`) do echo %%A > %temp%\ip.txt');
      Name := GetTempPath + 'get_ip.bat';
      List.SaveToFile(Name);

      ZeroMemory(@ShExecInfo, SizeOf(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));

      with ShExecInfo do
      begin
        cbSize := SizeOf(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
        fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
        lpFile := PChar(Name);
        nShow := SW_HIDE;
      end;

      Win32Check(ShellExecuteEx(@ShExecInfo));
      WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
      CloseHandle(ShExecInfo.hProcess);

      List.LoadFromFile(GetTempPath + 'ip.txt');

      edtIP.Text := Trim(List.Text);
      edtPort.Text := '5432';
      edtUser.Text := 'postgres';
      edtPassword.Text := 'passwd';
    finally
      List.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Не все антивирусы любят temp.

Comment: @Qwertiy Он именно для того и придуман, чтобы писать временные файлы приложения

Comment: Да, но это не мешает некоторым антивирусам лочить запуск оттуда.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, благодарю. Прошу извинить за возникшее недоразумение